# Конвертирование изображений в .NET

Tags: .net, изображения, конвертация, формат

Ранее, я использовал [irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com/), создавал Process и передавал ему аргументы(Использовал [консольный режим](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/iviewcli.txt)):

`"что конвертируем" /silent /advancedbatch /convert="куда конвертируем"`, а тонкие параметры конвертации(DPI,уменьшение размера, формат) задавались в *.INI файле к программе.

Обновил версию программы(irfan) и после этого то, что работало перестало работать.

Может кто-нибудь имел дело со свежей версией данной программы и может подсказать, что не так?(Мб формат команды поменялся).

Существует какая-нибудь удобная альтернатива моего текущего метода конвертирования?

Comment: Может быть, просто изменился формат командной строки?

Comment: @VladD, как вариант, но свежую документацию я не нашел=(

Comment: Хм, а неужели у программы нету встроенной справки?

Comment: @VladD, в справке, вроде, точно такой же синтаксис.

Comment: Может gdіplus библиотека вам подойдёт?

Comment: @nick_n_a, хорошая ли у него производительность? Весь ли GDI+ обернут в .NET?